# Sort ArrayList<String> containing numbers and letters

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have an `ArrayList<String>` containing a list of 'Building Key' numbers.
Forgive me if this has been answered before I am struggling to find a solution by searching.

```
public class SortKeyNumbers {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        
        keys.add("1");
        keys.add("10");
        keys.add("2");
        keys.add("3");
        keys.add("3B");
        keys.add("12");
        keys.add("12C");
        keys.add("21");
        keys.add("32");
        
        Collections.sort(keys);
        
        System.out.println(keys);
        
    }
    
}
```

This gives me an output of `[1, 10, 12, 12C, 2, 21, 3, 32,3B]`
I know that this is as expected from `Collections.sort`
What I need is an output of `[1, 2, 3, 3B, 10, 12, 12C, 21, 32]`

What I am asking is help to write the correct `comparator` or `compareTo` to achieve the desired output.

Comment: *What I am asking is help to write the correct comparator or compareTo to achieve the desired output.* - where is your attempt? Maybe we can make a suggestion on how to improve it. We don't even know the full requirements. For example, can it only contain a single character at the end or multiple characters. What comes first "12" or "12C"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a comparator function which strips any non-digit characters out of the key and then parses it to an integer:

```
Collections.sort(keys, Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""))));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3B, 10, 12, 12C, 21, 32]
```

Comment: Seems so easy! I tried adding "12B" after adding "12C" but it doesn't sort them alphanumerically. Is there a way to incorporate that as well?

Comment: @tonkatommy. *Is there a way to incorporate that as well?* - write a proper Comparator and incorporate all your rules into the Comparator.

Comment: @tonkatommy if you first sort alphabetically (`Collections.sort(keys)`) and then use this function, those values will sort as you desire (because Java sort is stable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ArrayList.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and just compare only integers by removing non digits

```
keys.sort(Comparator.comparing(str-> Integer.valueOf(str.replaceAll("\\D+",""))));
```